# Disable email registration requirement in Drupal 7

Tags: users, emails

I've already removed e-mail validation, but the requirement that each user supply a unique e-mail address needs to be removed too. How can I go about doing that without resorting to a messy workaround like dummy e-mail addresses (which cause problems like making contact forms silently fail)?

Comment: Your query is not understandable.

Comment: When a new user registers, I want them to not have to enter an e-mail address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Drupal 6 and 7, the module [Optional Mail](https://drupal.org/project/optional_mail) will allow your users to register without providing an e-mail address.  (By the way, not sure what your use case is, but we're doing this on a site heavily using [Voip Drupal](http://voipdrupal.org/) so we're allowing phone number only users.)

Answer (score 4):

For removing unique e-mail address requirement see [Shared Email](http://drupal.org/project/sharedemail) module:

> The shared email module allows multiple users to use the same email address for different accounts. The module works for both registration and account updates.

Disabling email requirement for registration is quite complicated task because many things in Drupal use mail notifications. I can recommend to set special email `users.without.mail@yoursite.com` for users without emails.

Comment: I already removed validation, which removed the unique e-mail requirement. Using the "special" or dummy e-mail is not optimal because, as mentioned, it can cause silent failures in contact forms and the like.